# Stata - replace option in table command - keep missing

Tags: replace, tabs, stata

I am running the `table` command in Stata with the `replace` option as follows:

```
table di2000_C im0100 [pweight=hw0010], c(freq) row stubwidth(15) cellwidth(15) missing replace
```

I get the following output:

[image]

The problem is that the `replace` option does not store the two missing cells in the table as missing. It simply drops those from the dataset, as illustrated in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this so that those empty values for the statistics are stored instead of being dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question shows a double misunderstanding.

1. An empty cell in a table does not correspond to anything missing in Stata's sense.
2. An empty cell arises because there are no matching observations in the dataset. So there is nothing to `drop` and Stata does not `drop` anything.

If you want explicit zero frequencies for empty cells in your table, what you could do is apply `fillin` afterwards.

There is no reproducible example in your question, contrary to general Stack Overflow recommendations and detailed specific guidance at the Stata tag wiki.

Here as an alternative is a example you can run to show some technique. Using `pweights` would be in addition to the technique here.

```
sysuse auto, clear
table foreign rep78, replace
list 
fillin rep78 foreign
list 
replace table1 = 0 if _fillin
drop _fillin
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. fillin command completely solves my problem!